# Using MHRA, do I need to cite a translator when referencing an online text?

Tags: citations, online-resource, translations

My apologies in advance if this question is misplaced here. Using a reference like this (for online resourses)

> Heraclitus, 'Fragments Of Heraclitus - Wikisource, The Free Online Library', En.wikisource.org, 2014 http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Fragments_of_Heraclitus#Fragment_1 [accessed 24 October 2014]

do I need to include somewhere that the translator is John Burnet? I assume so, but I cannot find anything in the style guide to indicate where I would put the translator (maybe just, "Heraclitus, translated by John Burnet, ..." ?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the several reasons for citation is to give credit where credit is due.  Thus, you *must* cite the translator.  How to do so?  [Just like you would an editor](http://intranet.exeter.ac.uk/humanities/studying/subjecthandbooks/ml/referencing/).

Comment: And also, the translator may have made/corrected a mistake from the original text that could be relevant.